# Android Error in Select Query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Below is my database method which is causing the issue:

```
 public Cursor fetchRecord(String pin,String category)throws SQLException
{

Cursor c=mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]
{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PHONE,KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_PINCODE},
KEY_PINCODE + "= ?" + "AND" + KEY_CATEGORY + "= ?",
new String[]{pin,category}, null, null, KEY_NAME);

    if (c!= null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

it gets force close whenever i give input and click go button in the first activity
the log cat says:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ANDcategory": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, phone, category, pincode FROM details WHERE pincode= ?ANDcategory= ? ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be space between the pincode & category, in your where clause.

simply replace

```
"AND"
```

with

```
" AND "


public Cursor fetchRecord(String pin,String category)throws SQLException 
{ 

        Cursor c=mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]
 {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PHONE,KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_PINCODE},
KEY_PINCODE + "= ?" + 
" AND " + KEY_CATEGORY + "= ?",new String[]{pin,category}, null, null, KEY_NAME); 

    if (c!= null) { 
        c.moveToFirst(); 
    } 
    return c; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read the exception, it tells you everything you need to know:

```
syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, phone, category, pincode FROM details WHERE pincode= ?ANDcategory= ? ORDER BY name
```